# Contour integral qualitative behavior

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

consider a holomorphic function $f(z)$ and the paths $\gamma_1:(0,\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, t\mapsto r\cdot i\cdot e^{i t}$, $\gamma_2:(0,\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, t\mapsto r\cdot i\cdot e^{i (-t)}$ with $0<r<1$. Is it possible to tell something about the behavior of the following limit?

$$ \lim\limits_{r\downarrow 0} \left(\int\limits_{\gamma_1}\frac{f(z)}{\sin( z)}dz + \int\limits_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(z)}{\sin( z)}dz\right).$$

I have computed some examples and got zero as limit. Is it always true that the limit is zero?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the OP, on the curve $\gamma_1$, $z=ire^{it}$, beginning at $t=0$ and ending at $t=\pi$, while on $\gamma_2$, $z=ire^{-it}$ beginning at $t=0$ and ending at $t=\pi$.   Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{f(z)}{\sin(z)}\,dz&=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_0^\pi \frac{f(ire^{it})}{\sin(ire^{it})}\,(-r) e^{it}\,dt\\\\
&=i\pi f(0) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(z)}{\sin(z)}\,dz&=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_0^\pi \frac{f(ire^{-it})}{\sin(ire^{-it})}\,(r) e^{-it}\,dt\\\\
&=-i\pi f(0) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Upon adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, the coveted limit is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your arguments looks very reasonable. But I am confused because of the answer of User001 below, since it claims the opposite…Why did he had in mind and why is he wrong then?!

Comment: Hasti, You're welcome!  My pleasure.  I'm not really sure how others interpreted the question.  I wrote my assumptions, under which I believe that this is correct.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

The limit should be **non-trivial**, integrating with perhaps semi-circular indents around the poles that will lie on the contour.

I.e., use the parametrization, and go for a principal value integral.

Comment: There are no poles on the contours since $f(z)$ is analytic and $\sin(z)$ has zeroes only at $\ell \pi$ for integer $\ell$.

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV, using linearity of the integral, we combine the two integrals, which is now integration along a full circle.  Do you agree?

Comment: The paths are traversed in opposite directions.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.  I figured that would just be reconciled by factoring out $-1$.  @Dr.MV

Comment: And then going for P.V. integrals @Dr.MV.

Comment: **If** my thinking is correct, then reading up on some of Ron Gordon's answers on MSE regarding some pretty tricky P.V. integration using semi-circular indents can be very beneficial @HastiMusti.

Comment: @Dr.MV, I'm sure you have also done some work on P.V. integrals on this site, too -- I'm just not sure that I've read some of your work specifically on this type of integration.  But your answers are always excellent :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you obtain a integral along a full circle around 0? Could you please show me your calculations so that I can double check it?

Comment: @User001 There are no singularities on the contours since $f$ is analytic and the sine function has no zeroes on the contours.